# Is it possible to get the devtype of a USB wifi device?

Tags: wifi, udev

I know `udevadm info` gives the devtype of disks as `disk`. However, how would I get the devtype of a usb wifi adapter? (ie `wlan`, `wwan`, etc)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `lsusb` and find your device. I will post my `lsusb` as an example

```
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 13b1:0026 Linksys WUSB54GSC v1 802.11g Adapter [Broadcom 4320 USB]
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0a5c:2148 Broadcom Corp. BCM92046DG-CL1ROM Bluetooth 2.1 Adapter
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0a5c:4503 Broadcom Corp. Mouse (Boot Interface Subclass)
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0a5c:4502 Broadcom Corp. Keyboard (Boot Interface Subclass)
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0a5c:4500 Broadcom Corp. BCM2046B1 USB 2.0 Hub (part of BCM2046 Bluetooth)
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8086:0186 Intel Corp. WiMAX Connection 2400m
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b1d6 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd CNF9055 Toshiba Webcam
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Bus 002 Device 007 is the old wifi card and the format for the udev command with USB devices is

```
 udevadm info /dev/bus/usb/{BUS_NUMBER}/{DEVICE_NUMBER}
```

So I would enter  `udevadm info /dev/bus/usb/002/007` to get the info.

What you need to enter depends on your `lsusb` results.

For USB network-related device types to be used by `udev`:

1. Get the name of the interface from `ifconfig`.
2. Then run:
   `udevadm info /sys/class/net/{name of interface}`
3. Search for: `ID_TYPE=`. This type will be more specific than `DEVTYPE=usb_device`. A type of `generic` may indictate the driver hasn't set a type for this device.