# Get udev DEVTYPE of ethernet interface

Tags: udev, network-interface

How do I determine the `DEVTYPE` udev property of an ethernet interface (On my machine it's `enp3s0`) as required in the [`systemd.network` documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.network.html#Type=).

**Edit**

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/enp3s0/uevent
INTERFACE=enp3s0
IFINDEX=2
```

Does not yield the `DEVTYPE` property.

**Edit 2**

In response to @Kevin Lemair's answer, the command yields neither the *required* `DEVTYPE`, nor the `ID_TYPE` property.

```
$ udevadm info /sys/class/net/enp3s0
P: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0
E: DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:03:00.0/net/enp3s0
E: ID_BUS=pci
E: ID_MM_CANDIDATE=1
E: ID_MODEL_FROM_DATABASE=RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
E: ID_MODEL_ID=0x8168
E: ID_NET_DRIVER=r8169
E: ID_NET_LINK_FILE=/usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link
E: ID_NET_NAME=enp3s0
E: ID_NET_NAME_MAC=enx7427eaa9df7d
E: ID_NET_NAME_PATH=enp3s0
E: ID_OUI_FROM_DATABASE=Elitegroup Computer Systems Co.,Ltd.
E: ID_PATH=pci-0000:03:00.0
E: ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_03_00_0
E: ID_PCI_CLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Network controller
E: ID_PCI_SUBCLASS_FROM_DATABASE=Ethernet controller
E: ID_VENDOR_FROM_DATABASE=Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
E: ID_VENDOR_ID=0x10ec
E: IFINDEX=2
E: INTERFACE=enp3s0
E: SUBSYSTEM=net
E: SYSTEMD_ALIAS=/sys/subsystem/net/devices/enp3s0 /sys/subsystem/net/devices/enp3s0
E: TAGS=:systemd:
E: USEC_INITIALIZED=18190174
```

Comment: Ok, so apparently, this property is not always set. It worked for me and for this question too: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/271878/is-it-possible-to-get-the-devtype-of-a-usb-wifi-device

Comment: @KevinLemaire - afaik, it's never set for ethernet devices: ["when I did the initial DEVTYPE support, it was easy for “wlan” since the subsystem is taking care of creating the netdev. (...) So was “bluetooth” since it is one central place and same applied to “wimax”. The “wwan” was lucky part since the drivers already did the FLAG_WWAN to pick the wwan%d ifname. _For Ethernet cards it was just the wild west. **So I left them out of the picture.**_"](https://lists.freedesktop.org/archives/systemd-devel/2014-January/015999.html)

Answer (score 5):

Considering interface name is enp3s0, you can get the `ID_TYPE` when running the following command:

```
udevadm info /sys/class/net/enp3s0
```

---

A type of generic may indicate the driver hasn't set a type for this device.